# Convert DAAppearanceTime to Date

Tags: swift, date-conversion, diskarbitration

How can the *DAAppearance* Time from the *Disk​Arbitration* be converted to a valid Timestamp?

I tried the following:

```
  if let appearanceTime = diskinfo["DAAppearanceTime"] as? NSNumber{
                            print(appearanceTime)
                            let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(appearanceTime))
                            print(date)                             
                        }
```

I get the correct *DAAppearanceTime* back from the function but the wrong Year after the conversion:

511348742.912949

1986-03-16 09:19:02 +0000

Comment: You are getting correct date for timestamp `511348742.912949` you can confirm it here http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Comment: So that means that the DiskArbitration is providing false numbers? The time is correct but my USB stick is not connected since 1986

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"DAAppearanceTime"` key is not officially documented, but the DiskArbitration framework is open source.

[DAInternal.c:](https://opensource.apple.com/source/DiskArbitration/DiskArbitration-288.1.1/diskarbitrationd/DAInternal.c.auto.html)

```
 const CFStringRef kDADiskDescriptionAppearanceTimeKey  = CFSTR( "DAAppearanceTime"  );
```

[DADisk.c:](https://opensource.apple.com/source/DiskArbitration/DiskArbitration-288.1.1/diskarbitrationd/DADisk.c.auto.html)

```
/*
 * Create the disk description -- appearance time.
 */

time = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent( );

object = CFNumberCreate( allocator, kCFNumberDoubleType, &time );
if ( object == NULL )  goto DADiskCreateFromIOMediaErr;

CFDictionarySetValue( disk->_description, kDADiskDescriptionAppearanceTimeKey, object );
CFRelease( object );
```

So the value of that key is what [`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1543542-cfabsolutetimegetcurrent) returns, and that is the

> Absolute time is measured in seconds relative to the absolute reference date of Jan 1 2001 00:00:00 GMT.

You convert it to a `Date` like this:

```
if let time = diskinfo["DAAppearanceTime"] as? Double {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: time)
    print(date)
}
```

For the value `511348742.912949` this results in the
date `2017-03-16 09:19:02 +0000`.